# Manipulate bytes with assembly

Tags: solidity, assembly, bytes, bytes32

Using assembly only, how do I switch, for `A0b86991c6218b36c1d19D4a2e9Eb0cE3606eB48`, the last 20 bytes of the second 32-bytes from the bytes variable below, and keep the rest as it is?

- Original `bytes`:

0x000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000004000000000000000000000000037cb1a23e763d2f975bff3b2b86cfa901f7b517e0000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000056bc75e2d631000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000040000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000200000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000d2bd5d716ee38d00000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000c0e05cf2a0fe6f

- Second `32-bytes`:

`0x00000000000000000000000037cb1a23e763d2f975bff3b2b86cfa901f7b517e`

- Last 20 bytes to switch for `A0b86991c6218b36c1d19D4a2e9Eb0cE3606eB48`:

`37cb1a23e763d2f975bff3b2b86cfa901f7b517e`

- Final `bytes`:

0x0000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000040000000000000000000000000A0b86991c6218b36c1d19D4a2e9Eb0cE3606eB480000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000056bc75e2d631000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000040000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000200000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000d2bd5d716ee38d00000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000c0e05cf2a0fe6f

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This should work for you:

```
// SPDX-License-Identifier: UNLICENSED

pragma solidity ^0.8.13;

import "hardhat/console.sol";

contract Manipulation {
    // 0x000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000004000000000000000000000000037cb1a23e763d2f975bff3b2b86cfa901f7b517e0000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000056bc75e2d631000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000040000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000200000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000d2bd5d716ee38d00000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000c0e05cf2a0fe6f, 0x000000000000000000000000A0b86991c6218b36c1d19D4a2e9Eb0cE3606eB48
    function test_manipulateBytes(bytes memory originalBytes, bytes32 substringBytes) public view returns (bytes20, bytes memory) {
        bytes20 chunk;
        assembly {
            chunk := shl(mul(12, 8), substringBytes) // get the last 20 bytes of substringBytes (shift by (32 - 20 = 12) * 8 bits)
            mstore(add(originalBytes, 76), chunk) // store the corresponding slice of substringBytes at the position of originalBytes
        }
        
        return (chunk, originalBytes);
    }
}
```

---

In my Remix IDE it returns `0x0000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000040000000000000000000000000a0b86991c6218b36c1d19d4a2e9eb0ce3606eb480000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000056bc75e2d631000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000040000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000200000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000d2bd5d716ee38d00000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000c0e05cf2a0fe6f` as `originalBytes`. Which is equal to the output you specified as desired in your question.

**The simplified steps are the following:**

- Get the last 20 bytes of the bytes32 substring input *(transform `0x00000000000000000000000037cb1a23e763d2f975bff3b2b86cfa901f7b517e` ---> `0x000000000000000000000000A0b86991c6218b36c1d19D4a2e9Eb0cE3606eB48`)*
- Store the 20-bytes chunk as `chunk`
- Load the chunk at the correct bytes position at `originalBytes`

---

***P.S.*** *It's pure assembly, except for the `bytes20 chunk` declaration.*

---

**Update:**

I noticed that there's a `22` bytes shift after the index `96` in the outputBytes array, though the preceding characters and the ones starting at `96+22` remain original.

I identified the problem only when I decided to test a more populated bytes value with some characters set at index `97`.

***So here's a fixed version of this Yul code that doesn't mask the original bytes in the `96-22` range (version №2):***

```
// SPDX-License-Identifier: UNLICENSED

pragma solidity ^0.8.13;

contract Manipulation {
    // To test whether other characters are overwriten due to padding: 0x111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111114111111111111111111111111137cb1a23e763d2f975bff3b2b86cfa911f7b517e1111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111156bc75e2d631111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111141111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111211111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111d2bd5d716ee38d11111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111c1e15cf2a1fe6f, 0x000000000000000000000000A0b86991c6218b36c1d19D4a2e9Eb0cE3606eB48
    // Normal plain test: 0x000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000004000000000000000000000000037cb1a23e763d2f975bff3b2b86cfa901f7b517e0000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000056bc75e2d631000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000040000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000200000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000d2bd5d716ee38d00000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000c0e05cf2a0fe6f, 0x000000000000000000000000A0b86991c6218b36c1d19D4a2e9Eb0cE3606eB48
    function test_manipulateBytes(bytes memory originalBytes, bytes32 substringBytes) public pure returns (/*bytes20, */bytes memory) {
        bytes20 chunk;
        // bytes memory outputBytes = new bytes(originalBytes.length);


        assembly {
            chunk := shl(mul(12, 8), substringBytes)
            mstore(add(originalBytes, 76), or(and(mload(add(originalBytes, 76)), not(shl(96, 0xFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFF))), chunk))    
        }

        return (/*chunk, */originalBytes);
    }
}
```

With the version №1, if you call the `test_manipulateBytes(bytes memory originalBytes, bytes32 substringBytes)` function with this bytes value: `0x111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111114111111111111111111111111137cb1a23e763d2f975bff3b2b86cfa911f7b517e1111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111156bc75e2d631111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111141111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111211111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111d2bd5d716ee38d11111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111c1e15cf2a1fe6f`, you'll see that the output is not `0x1111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111141111111111111111111111111a0b86991c6218b36c1d19d4a2e9eb0ce3606eb481111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111156bc75e2d631111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111141111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111211111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111d2bd5d716ee38d11111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111c1e15cf2a1fe6f`, but `0x1111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111141111111111111111111111111a0b86991c6218b36c1d19d4a2e9eb0ce3606eb480000000000000000000000001111111111111111111111156bc75e2d631111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111141111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111211111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111d2bd5d716ee38d11111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111c1e15cf2a1fe6f`.

So there will be unexpected 000s *(zeros)*.

To fix that, please use the version №2 code that I shared above, it addresses the problem by clearing the bytes range that we want to further replace, and thereby doesn't cause the ***zeroed padding issue***.

***Then the result will always be correct.***

---

*The function is pretty much generic and can be utilized universally if you allow the `replaceOffset` and `replaceChunkSize` arguments and do some slight updates* .

Comment: Nice! Thanks a lot.

Comment: I updated my answer with some fixes of the issues that I noticed recently. Please check it out :)

Comment: Awesome! Pretty educative as well. We need more Yul brainers here. Keep it coming.